# Is there a list of UPnP Type URN's?

Tags: c++, winapi, upnp

I am trying to do Create an Forward Port on my Router using the UPnP API's from Windows in c++.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/upnp/synchronous-searching

When trying to find an Device by Type using FindByType(), there is an Parameter that requires the Object Type as an BSTR, in the Microsoft Documentation Example they used:

urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:multidisk-dvd

however they did not left any other hints of how i could find Objects that have a different Object Type (My Router Device in this case).

Is there some kind of List that holds all the possible Object Types, or something else that could help me?

Comment: Maybe you have to know what you are looking for e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol

Comment: The device types are controlled by the UPnP Forum. Maybe you'll find more information [here](https://openconnectivity.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In the following document [Discovering Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/upnp/discovering-devices),

> You can search for devices in three ways: by type, [by UDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/upnp/nf-upnp-iupnpdevicefinder-findbyudn), and by
> asynchronous search (which is a search by device type).

[C++ UPnP samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/search?q=CreateAsyncFind) that discover and control UPnP devices found on the network.

[Well-known devtypes](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/UPnPGenericUCP/cpp/devtype.txt):

```
upnp:rootdevice All Root Devices
urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1 Internet Gateway Devices
urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:lighting:1 Lighting Devices
urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:reminder:1 Reminder Devices
urn:microsoft-com:device:DimmerDevice:1 UPnP SDK Sample Dimmer Devices
```

Comment: You can search for devices by All Root Devices(upnp:rootdevice) or by UDN (e.g. uuid:e8f85dfd-ff...) if you know. @Schrottiy Any update?